# Generating a dictionary in python with all possible cominations of given variables

Tags: python, math, data-structures, dictionary, combinations

I want to have a dictionary with keys all in this format.

[player_bullets "[0-6]",player_last_block "Boolean",player_prev "[1-3]",comp_bullets "[0-6]",comp_last_block "Boolean",comp_prev "[1-3]"]

and values all of [1/1,1/1,1/1]

The problem is that there need to be 1764 different entries(7*2*3*7*2*3).

If anyone can help me generate this dictionary, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
itertools.product(range(0,6), [True,False], range(1,3), ...)
```